# Ampliar Imagem do imageView Android

Tags: android

Estou querendo ampliar uma imagem do `imageView` ou seja fazer aquele efeito igual do whatsapp quando se recebe uma imagem e o usuário clica na imagem ela se abre.

Comment: Você quer fazer com uma unica foto ou você tem um grid? @AlessandroBarreto

Comment: So queria poder ampliar a imagem fazer o zoom e etc.  Efeito comum quando você quer ver uma imagem melhor.

Comment: O que você já tem feito? eu tenho um exemplo pronto porem ele busca direto do SD card. @AlessandroBarreto

Comment: Então na época eu tinha resolvido meu problema com uma lib de terceiros! Mais Você poderia me passar seu exemplo para eu da uma estudada? Bom eu ja sei buscar a imagem tanto da galeria e tanto o usuário tirando a foto do próprio app

Comment: Vou postar o conteúdo principal "o pulo do gato"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou colocar  "*o pulo do gato*" apenas porque o exemplo que fiz é muito grande:

Estava utilizando uma `GridView` para exibir todas as imagens mas você pode ter uma `imageView` normal.

```
grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings);

        grid.setAdapter(adapter);

        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewImage.class);

                i.putExtra("filepath", FilePathStrings);                
                i.putExtra("filename", FileNameStrings);            
                i.putExtra("position", position);

                startActivity(i);
            }

        });
```

Aqui é a Activity que será iniciada no click da foto :

```
public class ViewImage extends Activity {


    ImageView imageview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.view_image);

        Intent i = getIntent(); 
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");

        String[] filepath = i.getStringArrayExtra("filepath");

        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);     

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]);

        imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }
}
```

Aqui o Layout em full screen após clicar na foto:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Essa foi a minha solução pois eu tinha uma descrição de produtos com uma imagem do mesmo abaixo e precisava que o usuário conseguisse ver a imagem em tamanho maior, apenas alterei o `GridView` para `ImageView` quando fui implementar.

Comment: Valeu, vou estudar aqui seu código obrigado por ajudar. E só uma duvida, o que seria esse FilePathStrings? o caminho da imagem?

Comment: Ok, é bem simples, apenas abro uma nova activity no evento do click e passo a imagem e tamanho real.